# How can i initialize Room database from Presenter (MVP)

Tags: java, android, mvp, android-room

I'm trying to implement Room database in my project, but i have a problem. 
I am using MVC pattern and in presenter, I want to initialize room database. But to do that, I need a context, which presenter should not have. What I am doing wrong?

My Room DB:

```
@Database(entities = {SportEvent.class},version = 1)
public abstract class RecommendedEventsDB extends RoomDatabase {

    private static RecommendedEventsDB INSTANCE;

public abstract SportEventDao sportEventDao();

//singleton instance of database
public static RecommendedEventsDB getRecommendedEventsDB(Context context){
    if(INSTANCE == null) {
        INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(),
                RecommendedEventsDB.class, "recommended_Events")
                .allowMainThreadQueries() //need to be deleted, for testing purpose only!!!
                .build();
    }
    return INSTANCE;
    }
}
```

And in Presenter i would like to initiate DB:

```
RecommendedEventsDB db = RecommendedEventsDB.getRecommendedEventsDB(context);
```

but i have not context...

Can you help me please?

Comment: View should have context ... but obviously it depends on how you implement it(If it's a real View class or Fragment or Activity there should be no problem to get Context)

Comment: But I want to initiate DB from Presenter layer (or Model Layer, for now i am just testing and learning) and in presenter or model layer i dont have a context...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There was a [talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k3IT-IJ0J98) about `Fragment`s (Google I/O 2016) according to which

> Fragments are part of the ? in MV?

(at about 9:30 min.) And `Fragment`s do have a `Context` as long as they are attached to an `Activity`.

An interesting point of view.

But if one insists on having an `Android`-free Presenter, then one can use an  `interface` (or two):

A Presenter needs an `interface` - let's call it `ViewInterface` -  to communicate with the `Fragment` or `Activity` or `View` to which it belongs. Without this `ViewInterface`, nothing can happen in the "real world".

The database (as a means of physically storing data and accessing stored data) is very much part of this "real world", so it is only fitting that the Presenter asks its `ViewInterface` to make someone or something instantiate the data storage facility and please come back with another `interface` so the Presenter can cause all the CRUD operations to happen. Let's call this one `DatabaseInterface`.

So basically, you have two `interface`s. The first one could be implemented by a `Fragment` or `View`

```
interface ViewInterface{
    // ...        


    DatabaseInterface getDatabaseInterface();
}
```

The second one can be implemented by another class which will then manage the database operations

```
interface DatabaseInterface{
    void insertNewCustomer(Customer customer);
    void deleteCustomer(long customerDbId);
    List<Customer> findAllCustomers();
    // ...

}
```

Comment: So i should initiate database in view layer and pass its instance to presenter (or model) layer via interface, where i will work with data. Am I getting it right?

Comment: @Jan Maloušek - basically yes. I'd really go that step and use the  "DatabaseInterface" (ok, I'm no good with names...) because the whole idea of MVP seems to be that "inner" components are not permitted to directly work with "outer" components. And IMO a database is an "outer component" from a Presenter point of view. My favourite [link](https://8thlight.com/blog/uncle-bob/2012/08/13/the-clean-architecture.html) may be helpful

Comment: yes I know, i am using interfaces, i just wanted to be sure, that i am getting right what you wrote, that i should initiate database reference in View when presenter ask for it through interface. Thanks a lot :)